# Como posso navegar e editar um arquivo txt em Java

Tags: java

Tenho um arquivo txt com um texto nele pesquisei na internet achei alguns métodos para a escrita e para leitura, porém tenho que editar um arquivo que é padrão assim alterando apenas algumas partes do arquivo. O que posso utilizar para fazer essa função? Por exemplo, na primeira linha do arquivo o caractere 8 ao 15 vai ser substituído por algum valor que vou digitar, ou um valor de uma variável.

Comment: Esse artigo talvez possa te ajudar [Manipulando arquivos com recursos do java 8](http://blog.caelum.com.br/manipulando-arquivos-com-recursos-do-java-8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código abaixo carrega todas as linhas do arquivo texto para memória, altera os caracteres 8 a 15 da primeira linha, e salva de volta para arquivo todas as linhas, inclusive a linha alterada:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path path = Paths.get("c:/temp/arquivo.txt");
        List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(path);

        String novoConteudo = 
            linhas.get(0).substring(0, 7) + "conteudo" + linhas.get(0).substring(15);

        linhas.remove(0);
        linhas.add(0, novoConteudo);

        Files.write(path, linhas);
    }
}
```

*Talvez você tenha que considerar mais aspectos como performance, *encoding* e garantias do conteúdo atual da primeira linha (para evitar exceções de *index out of range*).

Comment: Testei o código e me retornou o seguinte erro : Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 , sabe porque o mesmo ocorre

Comment: Agora funcionou aqui , obgd ^^